# A synonym for "again" that is widely used today?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wrote the following:

> She nodded to her dad, smiling again. His words made her feel like
>   a child again. That period of time when she felt absolutely safe.

As you can see, it reads awkward because two sentences end with *again*. I searched on [Thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/again) but none of the words seem to be widely used in cases like the one above (maybe *one more time* but then I would have repeated *time* twice.)

Anyone has another suggestion?

Comment: Why even bother with the first _again_? Why not: _She nodded to her dad, smiling. His words made her feel like a child again._

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is writing advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Once more" would work, since you're saying that something is happening at that very moment that has happened before.

Answer (score 2):

*Once more* avoids the problems you mention.

Answer (score 2):

You also could convey the same thing by restructuring the second sentence

> His words *carried her back* to feeling like a child.

or

> His words *carried her back* to the feelings of childhood.

P.S. I also agree with Zibbobz and Barrie's *once more*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll consider it for the second draft.